# Adding a tooltip Hover Feature on Wordcloud in python

Tags: python, hover, google-colaboratory, tooltip

I am working on a project where I have to make an interactive WordCloud. The word cloud is created from the text column of a data frame and I want to add a tooltip hover feature (i.e., when I hover over a word, the tooltip presents information from the data frame. I am using google Colab as my IDE. But I am unable achieve it

I have been using Streamlit to develop this feature, and I have tried inbuilt tools to handle this (but without success). I have also looked into Vega. But nothing is working. Please suggest some python packages, or resources to make it work.